# Meteor.js projects and dependency management

Tags: javascript, git, meteor, bower

I just made my first meteorjs project and I'm new to Bower as well. I want it to be fast for someone else to check out my project and set up. I also don't want to commit the .meteor/ folder. Would Bower work for this? Is there a package that supplies the contents of the .meteor/ folder that gets created when you create a project with `meteor create project-name`, which would be separate from the actual meteor.js package, right? Or is it accepted practice instead simply to commit the .meteor/ folder in the repo with my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

Add the `.meteor` directory to your project.

### Long answer

`.meteor` is created with a `.gitigore` so your database and other dynamically written files won't be added. The directory also contains the files: `release`, `packages`, and `versions` which are critical to reproducing your build environment.

- `release` specifies the meteor version
- `packages` specifies the names of the packages you have included
- `versions` specifies the versions of all directly and indirectly included packages